# Is there a command to recall last command for editing with memory of cursor position?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash

What I mean is like, if had a command chain: (here `|` references cursor position before i hit enter)

```
$ youtube-dl -f |18 --yes-playlist https://blah.blah.com    
$ x
```

what would be command `x` to recall that previous command with cursor before 18 so that i can edit that number super-quickly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any such shortcut, but if you just want to change the first occurrence of `18` in that line, you can use [history interaction](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html#Event-Designators):

```
^18^something-else
```

For example:

```
$ ls 18
ls: cannot access '18': No such file or directory
$ ^18^2003^
ls 2003
ls: cannot access '2003': No such file or directory
$ ^2003^a b^
ls a b
ls: cannot access 'a': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'b': No such file or directory
```

Comment: works just fine !